# PyCurl 7.19.0: get cookies from response using getinfo(pycurl.COOKIELIST)

Tags: python, cookies, libcurl, pycurl

I'd like to get the Cookies that have been carried with the response (`Set-Cookie: name=value; ...`).

When passing the info constant and the reference of an empty list:

```
set_cookies = []
c.getinfo(c.COOKIELIST, set_cookies)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: c.getinfo() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

*That was straightforward.*

I also tried this signature:

```
set_cookies = c.getinfo(c.COOKIELIST)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid argument to getinfo
```

*This is a bit vague, however.*

Getting the HTTP status code using `getinfo()` works fine.

I get a `200 OK` and `Set-Cookie` headers, of course (debugging with `c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)`).

Of course I've read

> With very few exceptions, PycURL constants are derived from libcurl constants by removing the CURLINFO_ prefix.

Maybe this is the exception?

In my opinion the documentation is a quite poor and does not contain any info about getting cookies sent with `Set-Cookie`.

References:

- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html
- http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#examining-response-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no method to get response cookies after calling `perform()`. Headers sent by the server can be captured using a callback function passed to the PyCurl instance while configuring with `setopt()`:

> CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION
>
> ```
>    Callback for writing received headers. See CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION
> ```

Example code excerpt:

```
    set_cookies = []

    # closure to capture Set-Cookie
    def _write_header(header):
        match = re.match("^Set-Cookie: (.*)$", header)

        if match:
            set_cookies.append(match.group(1))

    # use closure to collect cookies sent from the server
    c.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, _write_header)
```

References:

- http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#examining-response-headers
- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

  - http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html